# JQM Check Box Not Styling inside Webview ".trigger('create')"

Tags: jquery-mobile, webview, styling

Here is my ***javascript*** code snippet:

```js
<script>
function returnStringForID(param) {
var retStr =
param.replace(/[\. ,:-]+/g, '').replace(/'/g, '')
    .replace(/&/g, '').replace(/\(|\)/g, '');
return retStr;
}
$(document).ready(function () {
var chanId = 'Demo';
var fs_dyn = $('#fs_dyn');
var data = ['Sony', 'Pix', 'Max', 'Set'];

var seriesColors = ['#4000E3', '#FFC526', '#FF0000', '#C0504D'
, '#1F497D', '#4BACC6', '#8064A2', '#9BBB59', '#F79646', '#948A54'];

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
var checkId = "graphItem_" + i;
var color;
color = seriesColors[i];

var chanId = returnStringForID(data[i]);

var tmp = "";
tmp = "<input type='checkbox' checked='true' class='custom' value='" + data[i]
    + "'  id='" + chanId + "' name='" + chanId + "'/>"
    + "<label for='" + chanId + "' style='font-size:12pt;font-weight:bold;color:"
    + color + "'>" + data[i] + "</label>";

fs_dyn.append(tmp);

}
fs_dyn.trigger('create');

});

</script>
```

Here is the HTML:

```html
<td width='30%' style="vertical-align: top;" id="tdDynamic">
<fieldset data-mini='true' id='fs_dyn'></fieldset>
</td>
```

This code works perfect if done in raw html. However when inside a webview, checkbox doesn't style.
Also I have used `.trigger('create')` to style a nested collapsible in the same app which is also inside a webview, but that works fine.

PS: I am using JQM 1.3.1 version, just in case this helps.

Comment: Don't use `.ready()` use JQM events. To fix your problem you need to call this `.checkboxradio().trigger('create');` . Edit: to style collapsible and its' contents `.collapsible().trigger('create');`.

Comment: I just move the code out of `.ready()` event and it worked. :) +1 .If you could add this as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `pageinit` event which is equivalent to `.ready()` or any [jQuery Mobile events](http://api.jquerymobile.com/category/events/).

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/HJfvf/)**

```js
$(document).on('pageinit', function () {
  // code
});
```

Using `.ready()` in jQuery Mobile isn't recommended, please refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14468659/1771795).